# How to overlay CSS onto the main resource theme in Codenameone

Tags: codenameone

My goal is simply to have a UID which allows me to put a shadow around different components, but still have the main theme.res used in my project. I'm finding i can only have one or the other running in the simulator at once - this is my problem.

[image]

After a lot of messing in the theme and then research it seems that i can't achieve this shadow affect in the theme, but it has to be done in CSS. I followed the CN1 research pages to produce the CSS below which then gave me the ability to have shadow UIDs in my project

```
BottomShadow {
box-shadow: 2pt 22pt 22pt 0px rgba(61,59,61,0.48);
padding-bottom: 2mm;
padding-top: 1mm;
```

}

But i am finding that when I use the CN1 Settings > Enable CSS, this stops the project from using my main theme.res (most likely because the settings creates a theme.css.res which overides it). But i have lots of 'regular' UIDs in my main theme that i need to run, as well as locales. I have read about people being able to overlay the CSS on the main theme, but this doesn't work for me.

```
        theme = UIManager.initNamedTheme("/theme", "Theme");
    if (Display.getInstance().isTablet()) {
        UIManager.getInstance().addThemeProps(theme.getTheme("Theme_Tablet"));
    }
    try {
        Resources css = Resources.openLayered("/theme.css");
        UIManager.getInstance().addThemeProps(css.getTheme(css.getThemeResourceNames()[0]));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I either get CSS or the main theme running, not both. FYI here is my Console info, when i start the app in the simulator, if it helps. Thanks

```
Found theme.css file.  Watching for changes...
 CSS> Retina Scale: 1.0
 CSS> Input: C:\...\css\theme.css
 CSS> Output: C:\...\src\theme.res
 CSS> Acquiring lock on CSS checksums file C:\...\.cn1_css_checksums...
 CSS> Lock obtained
 CSS> C:\...\src\theme.res has been modified since it was last compiled.       Making copy at C:\...\css\.backups\theme.res.1570314993006.bak
 CSS> Waiting for web browser
 CSS> Opening JavaFX Webview to render some CSS styles
 CSS> Waiting for web browser
 CSS> Web browser is available
 CSS> Releasing lock
 CSS> CSS file successfully compiled.  C:\...\src\theme.res
 CSS> Watching file C:\...\css\theme.css for changes...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the CSS does for this particular case is create a screenshot of the effect as an image to create that shadow. So if you generated a CSS theme res you can just open it in the designer and export it. You can then reimplement it in your non-CSS theme with the exported resource and (image screenshots).

You also have the option of a theme overlay which requires some manual work. Load the CSS theme then load your theme as an overlay add theme instead of as a set theme. This is covered in the developer guide under [theme overlays](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-theming.html).

BTW I'm guessing you've seen this and don't like the effect or need to interact with it: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/in-the-shadow.html

Comment: Point 1 and 3 are for images and i am using shadow on containers. I am trying the option 2, using overlays, but still struggling, yet I use overlays successfully with normal themes. So i read that CSS creates a theme.res, so i created a 2nd res file called overlayed.res. If i just run 

theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");    

then i get the css but none of my main theme. If i then add underneath

Resources mainTheme = Resources.openLayered("/overlayed"); UIManager.getInstance().addThemeProps(mainTheme.getTheme("overlayed"));    

then i get the overlayed theme and not the css.

Comment: To add that i don't actually have a theme.css.res file in my project anywhere, so unsure how that is created. Just refering to "/theme" (as my file is /css/theme.css) seems to be enough to get the css loading. For clarity my project has files /src/theme.res, /src/overlayed.res, /css/theme.css. I have tried refreshtheme() without any difference.

Comment: CSS overrides the existing theme file in its modern incarnation. As I explained it generates an image representing the shadow and uses that. If you open the newly created theme.res in the designer tool you would be able to see exactly what it does and use the image. In the overlayed theme remove the deriveFromNative theme constant as it's too aggressive for overlay and try to avoid things that might collide with the css. Although I think removing that hint alone would be enough.

Comment: Cracked it. So i made sure my app was showing the shadows (and wasn't enabling any previous theme.res uiid's). I then opened the theme.res (it didn't show anything from my CSS which confused me at first, just looks like the old one) > File > Export and point to any directory. This creates a build.xml file in that dir. Still in Designer > create File > New res file called Overlay. Then File > Import (the build.xml) and the 4 CSS UIIDs appear in a theme called Theme. I then saved the file back as theme.res and added UIIDs to it as normal. Then turn off CSS in settings and del the /css files. Thx